# Symfony Exception on Chrome (overview)

Tags: symfony, google-chrome, exception

I have a problem with the symfony exception css ([Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEUsM.png)) in google chrome since the last update of Chrome. Is it possible to have the CSS processed with a particular extension?

Comment: Have you tried with another browser to check that this problem is only with Chrome?

Comment: Hi and Welcome. To improve your experience on SO please take the tour, read how to ask and how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve